# how to access the router object in nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, frontend, nuxt.js

I am developing a website using nuxt.js which is based on vue.js. The site is a simple site with a number of pages on content. I want to create a component that knows where in the content it is and therefore need to access the router object. I have tried `$nuxt.$route.path` but get a error. How to i import the `$nuxt` or `$router` objects to access them in my component?

My template component

```
<template>
  <div>
      <hr>
      <p>{{ $store.state.menuitems[0] }}</p>
      <hr>
      <div class="artfooter">
        <span>i want name of current route here</span>
      </div>
      <br>
  </div>
</template>


<style scoped>
.artfooter{
    font-size: 0.8em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
</style>



<script>
  import store from '~/store/index'
  //how to import $nuxt object to access router??
  console.log(store)
  console.log(this.$router.path)
  // the above console.log reports error
  // Cannot read property 'middleware' of undefined

  export default {
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What are your errors? Can you include some code samples how you're trying to access it from your component?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You access it with `this`:

```
this.$route.path
```

Comment: I've tried `console.log(this.$route)` from within the `<script></script>` tags within a component (.vue file) but it reports that it is undefined!

Comment: `<script>
      import store from '~/store/index'
      console.log(store)
      console.log(this)

      export default {
      }
    </script>`

Comment: Ah yes, that doesn't work. The route object is located in your component/page/layout data object. Therefore you access it like any other data like `this.mydata`. So you have to move your logging into your component/page/layout object for being in the right scope. If you want to log it now when the component gets rendered you could put it in the mounted hook, like export default { mounted () { console.log(this.$route) }}

Answer (score 2):

Nuxt way of doing it by using either of it below:

```
// say that we are in "About Us" page

this.$nuxt.$route.name // returns 'about-us'
this.$nuxt.$route.path // returns '/about-us'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also access the route and router object from the global $nuxt object this way

```
 this.$nuxt._route
 this.$nuxt._router
```

Answer (score 0):

In Nuxt 3

you can use the useRouter composable (Example given below)

or useRoute composable

See more info here:

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-router

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-route

```js
<script setup>

const router = useRouter();

const someFunction = () => {
    // directly use router
    router.push('/some-path')
}

</script>
<template>

<div>{{ router.path }}</div>

</template>
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as general methods are concerned, I personally think that the best method is:

```
const store = window.$nuxt.$store
const router = window.$nuxt.$router
```

However, it should be noted that:

> $ nuxt cannot be accessed until initialization is complete, so this method needs to be used after initialization.